# Coverage for private constructor junit/emma

Tags: java, junit, junit4, emma

how can i write a @test class for a private constructor. i want to cover it with emma tool too.

```
public final class Product {

    private Product() {

    }
}
```

can someone suggest a simple way?

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to test private methods is to use **Reflection**.

There are many ways, but I would simple do this;

```
@Test
    public void testConstructorIsPrivate() throws Exception {
      Constructor constructor = Product.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
      assertTrue(Modifier.isPrivate(constructor.getModifiers()));
      constructor.setAccessible(true);
      constructor.newInstance();
    }
```

This will cover the constructor when running the coverage tool emma.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you should test private constructors, since they are part of the implementation. Write tests only for API methods with well-defined contracts.

Comment: This is a good point. I would agree that its usually (though not always) true. . I've found a few situations where I wanted to test a private method or constructor, and couldn't get at it via the public API for one reason or another.

Comment: The reason unfortunately is code test coverage scanners, e.g., Sonar, Emma.